# Developing and deploying games for Windows, Mac (& Linux)

Tags: cross-platform

I want to write games that run on all the major platforms.

I also want people to be able to play them by downloading a file and double clicking it. That means a single .exe/.app file.

I'm happy to use OpenGL directly for graphics (I'll mostly be working in 2D). What I don't know how to do is show a window, handle mouse/keyboard input and play sounds in a cross-platform manner.

I don't really mind what the underlying language is, though would prefer to avoid C++ and Java. C#, Ruby or Python would be preferable, in that order :)

Please, SO, save me from having to write Flash games!

Comment: "I want to write games that run on all the major platforms" - tall order?

Comment: You have removed pretty much all possibilities, so what about Adobe Air, or would you like it to be in Perl ? But frankly, Java would be your best option here.

Comment: @Mitch_Wheat not that much minecraft is one of the most popular game now and it run pretty much on all major platform (that is any platform that can have a java runtime)

Comment: maybe you can write games in silverlight that run on a few platforms, but these will need the plugin to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Java platform" works reasonably well, once the JRE is installed -- there is JWS (Java Web-Start) and the JRE can be packaged with the client I suppose.

There are a number of cross-platform game libraries for Java with OpenGL bindings such as [Java Monkey Engine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/). There are also 2D libraries such as  [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/). If you want a "really lightweight game library" (e.g. just basic OpenGL, keyboard/mouse IO, and precise timing) then I would highly recommend [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) which provides just that.

Java isn't suitable for all games -- but it be an option that worked very well for me for a course project. It was developed on Windows/Linux and played on Windows/Linux/OS X (get a non-ancient JRE installed for OS X ... bundled version is often severely dated.)

**Edit** I lied -- I *really really dislike Java* so I actually wrote my game/projects in [Scala](http://scala-lang.org) [it is a must to try for a JVM target] and just took advantage of the JVM and existing libraries ;-) They ran well with no performance/GC issues on Java 6u18+.

Comment: With Apple essentially deprecating Java support on OS X, does that platform have a viable future? I don't really want to package the JVM with my game if I can avoid it :)

Comment: (Also, LWJGL looks pretty nice.)

Comment: @nornagon There is an "official" (Mac update) JVM 6u13 available for OS X 10.5 now -- which is *okay* but misses some 18+ features -- and since Java 7 is still a dream... I wouldn't really worry about it. (I have no idea what apple plans on doing, but since most/all[?] of the JRE is open now, OS X runs on x86 hardware, and Mac popularity isn't waning...)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend C++ and [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), or [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) (whatever fits your purpose better).

Advantages by using C++ with either of said Frameworks:

- Guaranteed to be crossplatform (as there are C++ compilers for almost any Operating system existing on this Planet)
- No need for a virtualmachine, which might make the game arguably faster
- Both Ogre3D and Irrlicht have a non-restrictive License, that allows commercial use, without having to pay a fee.

There are also plenty of games, written using Ogre3D or Irrlicht:

- For Irrlicht:  http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/screenshots-projects.html
- For Ogre3D: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Projects+Using+OGRE

Ogre3D seems to be more mature than Irrlicht, judging by the amount of Applications and games, that is.

Comment: I've looked at Ogre3D before. It'd be nice if I wanted to do 3D, which I don't.

Comment: cross platform between Mac and other in C++ is a huge pain in the ass.

Comment: what about if we need 2D only?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be this cross platform, my advice would be to use some kind of "high level" platform, like Flash, or [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/).

Their business model seems smart to me: For small projects Unity is free, if you will grow enough so that it is no longer free for you, you will most likely be able to pay for the license (and you will get somewhat more advanced Pro version for that).

Comment: Unity seems pretty heavy -- and it's nontrivial to do 2D in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying out Ruby/[Gosu](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/), which looks like it can be deployed relatively easily on [Windows](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/wiki/RubyPackagingOnWindows) and [OS X](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/wiki/RubyPackagingOnOsx).

Comment: So you don't mind a runtime, so again why  not java (well not exactly) but jruby, as the JRE is more widely deployed than the ruby runtime.[http://jruby.org/]

Comment: The JRE isn't universal, and the ruby runtime is smaller :) Since I'm writing small, experimental games, I'd like the effort to play to be as small as possible for as many people as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular project I'm working on, [Processing.JS](http://processingjs.org) and [box2dweb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb) turned out to be the right answer.